# compiling s-functions for matlab

Tags: c++, matlab

I have been trying to make an s-function block in matlab with my c++ codes.I am using the following mexopts.bat file

> @echo off
>
> set MATLAB=%MATLAB%
>
> set PATH=%PATH%;c:\cygwin\bin
>
> set MW_TARGET_ARCH=win64
>
> set COMPILER=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
>
> set COMPFLAGS=-c -fexceptions "-I%MATLAB%\extern\include"
>
> set OPTIMFLAGS=-O3
>
> set DEBUGFLAGS=-g -Wall
>
> set NAME_OBJECT=-o
>
> set PRELINK_CMDS1=echo EXPORTS > mex.def & echo mexFunction >> mex.def
>
> set LIBLOC="%MATLAB%\bin\win64"
>
> set LINKER=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
>
> set LINKFLAGS= -static-libgcc -shared mex.def -L%LIBLOC%
>   -static-libstdc++
>
> set LINKFLAGSPOST= -lmex -lmx -lmwlapack -lmwblas -lstdc++
>
> set LINKOPTIMFLAGS=-O3
>
> set LINKDEBUGFLAGS= -g -Wall
>
> set LINK_FILE=
>
> set LINK_LIB=
>
> set NAME_OUTPUT=-o "%OUTDIR%%MEX_NAME%%MEX_EXT%"
>
> set RSP_FILE_INDICATOR=
>
> set POSTLINK_CMDS1=del mex.def

I am able to successfully compile sample mexfunction file from matlab using the 'mex' function,But when i try compiling an s-function(i took the example files with matlab) i get the following errror

```
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\simulink\include/simstruc.h:357:3: error: #error Must define one of RT, NRT, MATLAB_MEX_FILE, SL_INTERNAL, or FIPXT_SHARED_MODULE

C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\simulink\include/simstruc.h:467:78: fatal error: rt_matrx.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I am sure the c++ files are correct ,coz i took them from matlab examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All S-Functions require the following preprocessor symbols to be defined.

```
MATLAB_MEX_FILE
S_FUNCTION_LEVEL=2
S_FUNCTION_NAME=<your-sfun-name>
```

Add those to the `COMPFLAGS` in your batch file using the `-D` directive.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply.can u explain it a little more.Do i have to change the mexopts.bat file each time i compile an s function?

Comment: No, you don't need to change the file every time. Refer to the [*Override Option Details*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mex.html#bq6x7bj) section for instructions on how to set your own options when calling `mex`. You can create an m-file function that passes the right arguments to `mex` along with your S-Function name to simplify the process.